# Как изменять STATE в Aiogram

Tags: python

У меня есть машина состояний и в нее передается "название" и "описание", в конце когда я ловлю "описание" я записываю этот state в SQL таблицу. Но как мне добавить в state такие переменные как message.from_user.id и message.from_user.full_name?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно в таблицу сохранять данные пользователей, а точнее `id` и `full_name`. Вот так вот можно это сделать:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, full_name) VALUES (%s, %s)", (message.from_user.id,  message.from_user.full_name)
```

Comment: Смотри, есть машина состояний, по мере ее работы в state передается название и описание, если я запишу state в таблицу то получу в ней: id(это порядковый номер), название(name) и описание(description), но мне нужно еще добавить сюда id(user_id) и full_name. Момент в том что один человек может делать много подобных запросов, поэтому при записи id и full name должны храниться в state

Comment: Вот код https://www.online-python.com/x3aoziWRZ6

Comment: Тогда не знаю, жди своего спасителя

Comment: Все, я смог) код сейчас скину(если надо можешь посмотреть)

Comment: Хорош, если можешь, то отправь)

Comment: Держи(комм читай) https://www.online-python.com/SyvbEJNFXQ

Comment: Неплохой вариант